# Targeting SVG Paths within a group with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

Is it possible to have a function act only on paths only within a specified group?

I'm using this on an inline SVG image that has several paths:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("path").mouseenter(function() {
     etc....
```

and it does what I want it to do but it acts on every path and I only want it to work on specific paths. I've tried grouping the paths I want by using g id="example", so I can target just those but I can't get it to work. I don't know how to correctly reference them, is it even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to need to use a more specific selector.  I've used vanilla javascript to bind clicks on specific SVG elements, and it works just like regular html.  If you want the path inside of g#example just just use the jq child selector or $('#example path'), the latter being less efficient.

```
var test = document.getElementById('n');
test.addEventListener('click', function() {
  alert('hello');
});
```

[See fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/a6jy1m4z/8/)

Comment: Oh wow!! That did it!! Thankyou so much!! I've been pulling my hair out for hours on this, I just couldn't work out the correct way to reference it, I kept putting a dot in instead of a space! Thanks again